# Certificate can only be used by network service account

Tags: networking, security, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

Issues :

Our service is using one certification for partner service call. It worked well in IIS site which is running as network service account. But when we run test the code as administrator (domain account), the service call will always get 403 error (sub status code is 7: certificate is required).

We have verified:

- Attach debugger to the process we found the site can access to private key when running as domain account.
- The cert is in domain account's CURRENT_USER/MY cert store. And the cert authorization chain is good in cert store. The special thing of this cert is its root CA is an corporate internal CA. But the CA is already in the trust root.
- In IE, if we directly visit one https site, this cert is not in the pop-up list. But it do exist in the IE Options-Content-certificates-personal list.

Questions:

Seems the certificate usage is blocked by some security settings (Windows or some corporate domain policy), how to troubleshoot the issue ?

Comment: sounds like kerberos authentication to me.  kerberos authentication includes the ability to limit access and authentication of interactive accounts.

Comment: How to test if it is a kerboros issue ?

Comment: You can do a search for kerberos troubleshooting guides -- probably your best bet.  All I would be doing is trying to summarize what they say.